# Compile OpenNN with Qt in Windows and Mingw 5.30

Tags: qt, mingw, openmp, qmake, opennn

Im trying to compile the openNN Project with Qt.
Im using qt precompiled mingw32 for windows and the last opennn 3.1 projekt sources.
Opennn comes already with .pro Project files for direct use with qt creator/qmake.

However when i try to compile it i get the following errors:

```
   D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0x103): undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_start'
D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0x3d3): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_next'
D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0x3e0): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_end_nowait'
D:/Projekte/opennn_build/opennn/release\libopennn.a(testing_analysis.o):testing_analysis.cpp:(.text+0x64b): undefined reference to `GOMP_loop_dynamic_start'
```

it seems to be connected to openmp, however the *.pro files of opennn already contain the always suggested lines:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
```

trying to add the following didnt help either

```
LIBS+= -fopenmp
```

i need to make it work with qt, because i wanted to add it to an already existing qt project later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:
edit in openn/tests/tests.pro
and the "exampletitle".pro file of each example in openn/examples/"exampletitle"/

change:

```
win32-g++{
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libstdc++
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
}
```

to

```
win32-g++{
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libgcc
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static-libstdc++
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -static
LIBS += -fopenmp
}
```